# `TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene` and `EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75` can't be installed

Tags: bioconductor, software-installation

I think there is a problem with `TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene` and  `EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75`.  I'm struggling to install all of these packages as they pause at  `byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading` . Can anyone try to re-install them in their local machine because am not the only one who is having the problem, please? They used to work fine until a week ago!

As usual, I install the packages by:

```
BiocManager::install(c("Homo.sapiens", "EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75", "TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene"))
```

I also tried installing them individually:

```
BiocManager::install("EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75")
BiocManager::install("TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene")
```

It pause at:

```r
* installing *source* package ‘TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
```

sessionInfo( )

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] BiocManager_1.30.10 compiler_4.0.3      tools_4.0.3
```

I've tried with and without RStudio.
I'd be grateful if someone can try to replicate the error, please?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include how you are trying to install the packages? thanks.

Comment: Sorry @user438383, I forgot to add how I installed the pacakges. I edited the question now and added more details.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it on macOs 10.15 and it seems to have installed OK. Does the same problem occur if you try and install a different package via bioconductor, or a package using ``install.packages()``?

Comment: Oh, thank you. This is extremely strange because I tried it on my friend's computer and had the same problem. I can install any other package via Bioconductor without problem except for these three. Can I ask if you installed all three of them?

Comment: It's been a week and I've tried uninstalling R, RStudio and `RFrameworks ` countless times but still not working. I'm sorry but can I ask if if you used `BiocManager::install(c("Homo.sapiens", "EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75", "TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene"))` to install them?

Comment: This sounds like a system issue of some sort possibly having to do with Big Sur. Have you tried to install any of these with conda?

Comment: I would vote to close this as an identical (towards content) question has been asked at Bioc support where this belongs https://support.bioconductor.org/p/p133849/ and there were also similar questions at Bioc towards these database packages just this week. it is New Year's eve so please give Bioc people time rather than opening questions at other communities, I guess this is something that they can and should answer.

Comment: Sorry, I only wanted to see if someone can replicate the error because am having it in two machines. My apologies again and feel free to close the question.

Comment: It just paused indefinitely?

Comment: Did you mean it also paused indefinitely in your local machine when you installed it? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to successfully install these packages using:

```
BiocManager::install(c("Homo.sapiens", "EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75", "TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene"))
```

This completes without any errors / warnings (R v4.0.3 / macOS 10.16), so I don't believe the packages themselves/Bioconductor are 'broken', but I suspect you are having compiler issues due to the Big Sur update.

These are the steps I used to solve the problem:

1. Reinstall xcode command line tools (even if it says "up to date")

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

2. Install gcc & llvm via Homebrew ([instructions for installing Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)) or, if you already have gcc/llvm installed via Homebrew, skip to the next step

```
# This can take several hours
brew install gcc
brew install llvm
```

3. Once you have gcc & llvm installed via Homebrew:

```
brew cleanup
brew update
brew upgrade
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall llvm
```

4. Link some headers into /usr/local/include

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/

# You can safely ignore warnings like this:
#ln: /usr/local/include//tcl.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclPlatDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMath.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMathDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tk.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkPlatDecls.h: File exists
```

5. Create a new `~/.R/Makevars` file (if you already have a `~/.R/Makevars` file, save it in a different directory (away from `~/.R/`)) and include only these lines in the file:

```
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CXX1X=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX98=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX11=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX14=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX17=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++

LLVM_LOC = /usr/local/opt/llvm
CC=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gcc -fopenmp
CXX=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++ -fopenmp
CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

6. Compile a package from source in R/Rstudio

```
# To check whether openmp is enabled, compile data.table:
install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
```

7. If your package fails to compile, a couple of SO users have had to install a fresh gfortran (re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340), which you can download from https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/10.2-bigsur-intel

Once you can install packages from source without error/issue, update Bioconductor

```
BiocManager::install(version = "3.12")
```

Then, finally, you should be able to install your packages using

```
BiocManager::install(c("Homo.sapiens", "EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75", "TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene"))
```

Comment: You are amazing Jared, I'll go through the steps right now to see if it works, fingers crossed.

Comment: Awesome, it is working now. Thank you so much, Jared :)